# How to use DocuSign labels?

Tags: docusignapi

When sending a document to be signed, with DocuSign, I can choose a Document Label for the document with a dropdown list which I can manage administrative access. I don't, however, see the purpose of the Document Labels since I don't see any obvious way of using them to e.g. filter documents and create statistical reports. More information on the subject can be found [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels).

Can somebody describe to me the actual purpose of having these labels?

Here is screenshot of the Document Labels section:
[image: A screenshot of the Document Labels section]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I agree the documentation you linked is missing some detailed information on what they are for. In Classic (and soon again to be in the New UI) they were called Envelope Custom Fields, from the old documentation they are classified as "fields that can be used to **record information about the envelope, help search for envelopes and track information.** The custom fields are shown in the Message window when a user is creating an envelope. The custom fields are not seen by the envelope recipients."

Think of it as an invisible label that you can than use to report on later. In the Reporting section of DocuSign it's actually called "Custom Field" and can be added to reports:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't however provide an answer to the issue, but I can see how my question can be misinterpreted. I made an edit to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Envelope custom fields (Document Labels) are labels used to classify, record, and track information about envelopes sent by a user. These labels are shown to a sender when an envelope is being created; they are not seen by recipients.

The values for an envelope custom field can be free-text entries, or selected from a list of possible values. Envelope custom fields can be required or optional.

It is a metadata over envelopes. For instance, if you want to associate a case number or Invoice Number present in your system with an envelope but you do not want recipient to see it then you use Envelope custom fields (Document Labels) for this purpose. Then you can search envelope based on this label value in the Manage tab in your DocuSign Account. So Document Label helps in mapping data in your system with the envelopeId plus it helps you send extra data on an envelope which you do not want recipient to see.